# Converting timedate string with timezone to utc python

Tags: python

I have a a basic string + another string which reresents timezone. I'm trying to return the UTC equivalent..

```
timezone = "America/New_York"
scheduleDate = "2021-09-21 21:00:00"

dtimestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(scheduleDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').astimezone(
    pytz.timezone(timezone)).timestamp()
sdate = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(dtimestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
print(sdate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but not sure if there's a better approach for this. I haven't looked too closely at the `pytz` docs before.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pytz

timezone = "America/New_York"
scheduleDate = "2021-09-21 21:00:00"

# Convert to naive datetime
dt_naive: datetime = datetime.strptime(scheduleDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# localize datetime with ET timezone
dt: datetime = pytz.timezone(timezone).localize(dt_naive)

# normalize datetime to UTC time
dt_utc: datetime = pytz.utc.normalize(dt)

print(str(dt_utc))
```